# createFileCabinetPage causing error as "You do not have permission to perform that action"

Tags: google-apps-script

My Google script was running fine but all of sudden throwing error as "You do not have permission to perform that action". Below is the code:

```
  var curSite = SitesApp.getSiteByUrl("https://example.com/");
  var newPage = curSite.createFileCabinetPage(Test, (test + (new Date().getTime())), html);
```

Comment: Did the permissions change in the site? Does the site contain more than 500 children? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#createfilecabinetpagetitle-name-html

Comment: @Gerardo, Spot on! Do you know any way to increase the number of children pages? 

Also, Please add this as answer so I'll mark it as Correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @Pandurang, sorry i don't know any way to increase this number.

Comment: No worries, thank you for helping me to solve this issue. I'm using different branch now to create the children pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page#createfilecabinetpagetitle-name-html), there is a limit of 500 child pages for a parent site.